# MikTex 2.9 fails to install on windows 8.1 with mistake Windows API error 3

Tags: installing

I tried to install MikTex 2.9 on windows 8.1, but the operation failed with the following error:

> Windows API error 3: The system cannot find the path specified.
>   Details:path="C"\program files\Miktex 2.9\doc/fonts/ec"

Comment: Does anyone know how to fix this please ??

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't add comments like those. If you wish to change or add something to the question use the [edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/340755/edit) button located on the bottom left corner of the question window. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

The path looks strange/wrong.  I'd guess it should be C: not C". Also mixing forward and backslashes could be problematic on some environments.